# Django REST Meta data for M2M missing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

On my json output I don't seem to get key value pairs on my m2m field attribute_answers. see the code below. How to I add in the attribute_answers fields?

**json**

```
{
    "id": 20, 
    "name": "Jake", 
    "active": true, 
    "type": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Human", 
        "active": true, 
        "created": "2013-02-12T13:31:06Z", 
        "modified": null
    }, 
    "user": "jason", 
    "attribute_answers": [
        1, 
        2
    ]
}
```

**Serializer**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username')
    attribute_answers = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        depth = 2
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'active', 'type', 'user', 'attribute_answers')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance.

        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.name = attrs.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.active = attrs.get('active', instance.active)
            instance.type = attrs.get('type', instance.type)
            instance.attribute_answers = attrs.get('attribute_answers', instance.attribute_answers)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Profile(**attrs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a [Nested Relationship](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#nested-relationships). In your ProfileSerializer, you'll want:

```
attribute_answers = AttributeAnswerSerializer(many=True)
```

This will display all the attributes of each associated attribute_answer model and give you something like:

```
{
    "id": 20, 
    "name": "Jake", 
    "active": true, 
    "type": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Human", 
        "active": true, 
        "created": "2013-02-12T13:31:06Z", 
        "modified": null
    }, 
    "user": "jason", 
    "attribute_answers": [
        {"id": 1, "foo": "bar"}, 
        {"id": 2, "foo": "bar2"}
    ]
}
```